# how to provide file write permission for applet in jdk1.4

Tags: java, file, serialization, permissions, applet

I have problem in setup of policy file for applet.I am doing this first time and don't know how to set the policy file for applet in java.Actually I want to give the permission to the applet to write on the file system. for Which I will have to give file permission to the applet

So I make a file named .java.policy and and put the following code in it

grant codeBase "file:/C://res/applet/*" { permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\res\applet\test.txt", "read, write"; };

and save this in users\jindal folder now i set the JAVA_HOME as c:\users\jindal

but still I found the exception that

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\res\applet\test.txt write)

can any body please help what is wrong or what should i do.And I have to use jdk 1.4

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign your jar file

see also : http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/sign/signing.html

Comment: please tell me how can I sign my jar file

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better of signing the jar. Signing the jar elevates the privileges for the applet, which enables file access.

First you need a certificate. You can create a temporary one by:

```
keytool -genkey -alias certAlias
```

Sign the jar:

```
jarsigner -storepass yourPwd -signedjar output.jar in.jar certAlias
```